# Latin phrase for “at the moment” or “immediate”, temporal equivalent for in situ?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I know phrases like "in situ" which means in the current place/position, is there another phrase for the temporal equivalent which means "at the moment"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In sitū* literally means "in place" or "in the place"—it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the *current* place, and in fact usually means the *original* or *proper* place for something. For example, if archaeologists photograph an artifact "in situ", it's happening at the place where the artifact was found, not the museum it gets taken to later.

So if you want a temporal equivalent, you can use a bare ablative like *tempore*. Sallust frequently uses the phrase *eā tempestāte* for "at that time", but that's a fairly archaic usage of *tempestas*; I would adjust it to the more classical *eō tempore*.

Answer (score 1):

There are some synonyms, such as *nunc, modo, hic* ("now"), or *extemplo*, for "immediately, instantly" or "at the immediate".

Answer (score 1):

A moment of time = "punctum temporis"; in a moment = "statim" (often seen meaning "immediately"; "at once"; "instantly"); this moment = "ad tempus"; of great moment = "magni ponderis".

(All definitions from Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict.)